# Can we setup datadog alert threshold dynamically based on some template variable or tag

Tags: datadog

I want to setup datadog alert threshold different for each tag value passed, how can I do this?
One possibility is I create separate monitor for each tag value and use IN query for a perticular tag value. it will be bit hectic to manage those numbers of monitors.

Comment: At first glance, it is not supported. Can you describe a bit more your use case that requires all those thresholds? There may be a way to normalize the submitted metric and get a single monitor for all. Either normalize at submission or generate another metric that would include the threshold for each context.